# LoadRunner Automatic Transactions

Tags: transactions, action, loadrunner

i notice that in LoadRunner 12.02 under Runtime Settings -> Miscellaneous -> **Automatic Transactions** could be checked the option: *define each action as a transaction.*

If I can handle action as a transaction so what's the really difference between theme? In which case could be better to use one instead of the other?

Ty in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try them out, see what happens in your result set.  Be curious...

By the way, both options are covered in the downloadable tutorial, the printed documentation, the online documentation, the online help and the training classes...   Be curious.....

Comment: Thank you James. I've tried to register a script in both ways. Didn't find any differences between them.

Comment: If you didn't observe any differences in the performance test report upon making changes then there is not much I can do to add clarity

Answer (score 0):

Define each action  as transaction:

By enabling this it will give you performance measurements for each and every action in the script.

Define each step as transaction :

By enabling this it will give you performance measurements for each and every request like web_custom_request, web_submit_data, web_url etc

Comment: Welcome to SO, please give this a read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer